# XMP profile in CPU-Z : Can't get the memory timings? (even with activated XMP)

Tags: memory, overclocking, cpu-z, memory-timings, xmp

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered. I read through the whole forum but couldn't find an answer to my question. I use a prebuilt PC from HP Omen with 4 x 16GB DDR4-3200 ram sticks from Kingston. [(Thaiphoon Burner - Summary)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxsae.png)

Maybe I'm getting something completely wrong, I just can't understand that the following timings are displayed in the CPU-Z tool under the XMP profile: **18.0-21-21-39** at 3200 MHz [(CPU-Z - SPD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBX9y.png). But the timings that are used are those of JEDEC#13: **22.0-22-22-52** [(CPU-Z Memory)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYmVG.png) even with XMP enabled via the Omen Gaming Hub. (Unfortunately, it is not possible via bios, as HP does not allow this. Only with their app)

To my shock, when I installed Intel XTU, the XMP profile even had the same timings as JEDEC#13: **22.0-22-22-52** [(Intel XTU - XMP Profile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ruww.png). The default preset also has the same timings: **22.0-22-22-52** [(Intel XTU - Default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4E7b.png)

I just ask myself, are these the XMP settings that I should have, even though the XMP profile of CPU-Z says something different? Or do I have to manually take over the CPU-Z XMP profile timings via Intel XTU? Is everything working as it should and I understand something completely wrong?

Kindest regards

Comment: If you have four RAM sticks, you could be subject to additional limitations.

Comment: Why are you so worried about these timings? For all practical purposes, you are going to be hard pressed, to notice let alone measure a performance difference. However, your timings, are matching the table in the first screenshot exactly. Outside of benchmarks, your unlikely to notice single digit FPS differences, probably wouldn’t even notice them.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah ok, thanks for the info. I thought better timings would have an advantage in everyday use / gaming. I just wanted to achieve the XMP values ​​(CPU-Z XMP Profile, XMP Certified) or thought I would achieve them when I activate XMP.

Comment: @DanielB Ah I understand. Yes, then it may well be that that is the limitation in my case. I always thought that it could just limit the frequency (3200MHz). But yes, then of course it can also have an effect on the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Per your images, your sticks of ram are 1.20v. Note that the SPD chart from CPUZ shows JEDEC #13 for your frequency at 1.2v, but that the XMP-3200 profile it displays requires 1.35v ram. so while your SPD will support that mode, the ram sticks won't.